# How to clear the screen from command line in GAP

Tags: bash, readline

Normally I can clear the screen with <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> but while running [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), the key combo  <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> just displays the last command entered.

Comment: This probably depends on your terminal emulator. Anyways, ctrl+L works for me (in GAP 4.8.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAP [documents](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chapInd.html) no obvious/direct way to do this, but you can run system commands from its prompt which may do it, e.g., using [**`Exec`**](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap11.html#X81402C91833986FC):

```
gap> Exec( "clear" );
```

Comment: can you recommend any resources for learning about how system commands work in Bash?

Comment: There's a lot: in "system", I was referring to any command that could be run using [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), which covers a lot of territory.  GAP has its own command-language, and provides (like some other programs) a way to use shell commands (or on Windows, analogous commands).